# Highlight part of the code in a Jupyter cell

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, highlight

Is there a way to highlight certain lines of a Jupyter cell? Something similar to the following image (I created that with a photo editor):

[image]

I don't mean a selection with the cursor, but something permanent. 
This would be useful for presentations when you want to highlight newly added code for example.

Comment: It's probably possible to write some sort of javascript plugin to do that, but it might interfere with the existing CodeMirror syntax highlighter. I think it would be easier just to use a markdown cell and write some custom html there with inline css.

Comment: Using markdown would be a workaround but I also need to be able to execute the cells as code during the presentation.

Comment: As a potential workaround, this [jupyter extension](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/highlighter/readme.html) can highlight markdown cells.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Jupyter notebook extension provided below allows you to highlight ranges of lines in a code cell. Install and enable it as follows:

```
$ jupyter nbextension install codehighlighter.js --user
$ jupyter nbextension enable codehighlighter --user
```

Then a button with a [lightbulb icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/lightbulb-o) will appear on your Jupyter notebook toolbar. Pressing that button will highlight the selected lines (or, if there is no selection, the current line) in the current code cell.

The highlights will be saved with the notebook (as cell metadata) but will not be automatically enabled when the notebook is (re-)opened. In order to show the saved highlights you must press the **Restore highlights** button (the one with a [bars icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/bars)).

---

#### codehighlighter.js

```js
define([
    'base/js/namespace'
], function(
    Jupyter
) {
    function load_ipython_extension() {

        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = '.codehighlighter { background: yellow; }';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

        var highlight_code_in_cell = function (cell, from, to) {
            var cm = cell.code_mirror;
            for ( var lineno = from; lineno < to ; ++lineno )
                cm.addLineClass(lineno, 'background', 'codehighlighter');
        }

        var highlight_selected_code = function () {
            var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
            var cm = cell.code_mirror;
            var from = cm.getCursor('from');
            var to = cm.getCursor('to');
            var endLine = (to.ch > 0 ? to.line + 1 : to.line);
            highlight_code_in_cell(cell, from.line, endLine);
            if ( ! cell.metadata.codehighlighter )
                cell.metadata.codehighlighter = [];
            cell.metadata.codehighlighter.push([from.line, endLine]);
        };

        var highlight_from_metadata = function() {
            Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().forEach(function(cell) {
                if (cell.metadata.codehighlighter) {
                    cell.metadata.codehighlighter.forEach(function(range) {
                        highlight_code_in_cell(cell, range[0], range[1]);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        function registerAction(action_name, action) {
            var prefix = 'codehighlighter';
            return Jupyter.actions.register(action, action_name, prefix);
        }

        var hilite_code = registerAction('highlight-code', {
                                         icon: 'fa-lightbulb-o',
                                         help    : 'Highlight selected code',
                                         help_index : 'zz',
                                         handler : highlight_selected_code
        });
        var restore_hilites = registerAction('restore-highlights', {
                                         icon: 'fa-bars',
                                         help    : 'Restore highlights',
                                         help_index : 'zz',
                                         handler : highlight_from_metadata
        });

        Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([hilite_code, restore_hilites]);
    }

    return {
        load_ipython_extension: load_ipython_extension
    };
});
```

Comment: Almost excellent! Any way to save the hightlights with the notebook?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for that!

Comment: To continue: How does one install this in a browser using Jupyter? [Installing jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) helps a little: 1: the extension needs to be installed with `jupyter nbextension install`. But `<nbextension require path>` isn't clearly defined in `jupyter nbextension enable <nbextension require path>`.

Comment: Another way to ask this question is, in the `enable` command
   `jupyter nbextension enable <the entry point> --user`
what should `<the entry point>` be?
Thanks, Arthur