# Is there a way to change the highlighted code in a cell on Jupyter notebook to all lowercase?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I was wondering if there was a way/shortcut to change the highlighted code in a cell to all lowercase?

Thanks

Comment: Well easy way would be to copy the text and put it in triple quotes (`''' text goes here '''`) and do `print(''' text goes here '''.lower()) `

Comment: By "highlighted" do you mean "selected", or do you mean "syntax-highlighted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension that add an icon to your jupyter toolbar.
you can find more information at this link:
[Highlight part of the code in a Jupyter cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460002/highlight-part-of-the-code-in-a-jupyter-cell)